# Error on a class present in an implemented local Android Archive (aar) and compileOnly Java Archive (jar)

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have these two local dependencies in my build.gradle:

This one is in "compileOnly"

```
/libs
└─com.app.device.sdk.jar
    └───com
        └───app
            └───device
                ├───addon
                ├───auth
                ├───availability
                ├───barcodescanner
                └───ir
```

This one is in "implementation"

```
/libs-compiled
└───ArchiveSupport.aar
    ├───classes.jar
    │   └───com
    │       └───app
    │           └───device
    │               ├───alert
    │               ├───barcodescanner
    │               ├───eventlog
    │               ├───location
    │               ├───movement
    │               ├───ptt
    │               ├───pullcord
    │               ├───supervision
    │               ├───support
    │               └───telephony
    └───META-INF
        └───com
            └───android
                └───build
                    └───gradle
```

the package barcodescanner have a class with the same name, but different methods, is it possible to exclude the class only in the ArchiveSupport.aar?
Thanks in advance.

I've tried to use ProGuard rules or "implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs-compiled', include: ['*.aar']){ exclude ... }" but didn't work.

Comment: why do they have an identical package structure?

Comment: the packages are not created by me, I don't know this information.